# How to detect scroll to top in LongListSelector?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, scroll, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

For WP8, I am using LongListSelector to display list of items. I need to detect when the user has scrolled to top to load previous items in the list.

I have tried using `ItemRealized` event to detect when top element has been realised. There are couple of references where it is used to detect 'scroll to bottom'.

- http://rahulpnath.wordpress.com/2013/03/03/windows-phone-series-incremental-loading/#comments
- http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/TwitterSearch-Windows-b7fc4e5e

But this event gets fired for top element even when that user hasn't yet scrolled to that item. So, that doesn't for me to detect 'scrolling to top'.

Is there any way to detect this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the technique you are already using (`ItemRealized`), but just ignore the first event (since that's when the list is created. You can ignore it by simply setting a flag:

```
private bool _firstRealized = false;

void yourLLS_ItemRealized(object sender, ItemRealizationEventArgs e)
{
    // do your item detection here. For example:
    if (Data[0] == e.Container.Content) {

       // then
       if (!_firstRealized)
       {
          _firstRealized = true;
       }
       else
       {
          // woo - we've scrolled to top! Do your stuff
       }        
   }
}
```

Comment: But then, ItemRealized event is not fired for that item again (after ignoring first event).

Comment: only if the user does a very small scroll. If the user scrolls the list more than a screen down that item will no longer be realized, and will then be re-realized when they scroll back up.

Comment: additionally you could look at: http://nuncaalaprimera.com/2013/detecting-wp8-longlistselectors-end-of-scroll-stretching/

Comment: 1. I haven't experienced this behaviour. Even when I scroll 2-3 screens away from some item, ItemUnRealized event is not fired.
2. This code snippet from blog doesn't help. Already tried it, it fires everytime the user scrolls up or down (not when user has reached top or botton).

Comment: Use the `ItemRealized`. I just verified with a sample project and it definitely triggers when you scroll away by a screen and then come back. I've updated with more code.

Comment: ok, I tried some more variations. Items get unrealized and realized again only after number of items is greater than 20. If there are 20 items loaded in the list, you can scroll away as much as you want, itemRealized won't be called again.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this reference to get vertical offset 
[Get vertical offset of LongListSelector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121139/how-can-i-get-the-verticaloffset-of-a-longlistselector-in-wp8?answertab=active#tab-top)

and when vertical offset is 0 (or less than 10) then you are on top ViewPort.