# Exit Code - 2147220978 (0x8004020e)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

I am trying to make a text reader, but I found that when scrolling a large document, at some point whenever the texture memory reaches around 15000 the app just exits with code -2147220978 (0x8004020e).

What does it mean? Is there any work around?  I really need to be able to read large text documents.

Comment: Are you using Report Server 2005?

Comment: The error code isn't specific enough, pretty typical with COM error codes.  You'll need to at least post a stack trace that also shows unmanaged code stack frames.  With some expectation that something is going to go kablooey when you try to manipulate lots of data on a device with limited storage capability.

Comment: ok. but how do I do that? I'm really new to C# & VS2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you share minimal and relevant repro code? Just one snippet of XAML And one snippet of C# should be enough.

From what you're saying it really might be overloading the GPU with surfaces until the app crashes. It shouldn't ever happen, so I'm not sure this is the real cause.

In the meanwhile, have you tried virtualizng your ItemsControl? If you're using a ListBox have you tried switching to the new LongListSelector? If just switching to LongListSelector isn't enough, try using [ItemRealized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381752/continuous-pagination-with-longlistselector/13384007#13384007) and add some prefetching logic. If that doesn't work, you might have to create your own virtualizing logic either by manaully removing the Template from the visual tree once it goes out of view or creating a whole new 3rd party virtualized custom control. Maybe one of the 3rd party control vendors has something that would work here.

Comment: Yeah, that code is terrible when it comes to actually using what XAML has to offer. Don't initialize your own ListBoxItems, use ListBox.ItemTemplate and ListBox.ItemsSource dataibnding for that. Obviously you're going to run out of memory when you keep cranking out new ListBoxItems and not removing them from the Visual Tree.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to remove the content dynamically but the scrolling position got messed up. And I just couldn't get the right position by using VerticalOffset(because the ViewportHeight(=~107) doesn't match the ActualHeight(=556) of the listBox). So I have no idea what to do now:(

Answer (score 8):

The 8 means "error". The "004" means "this error is specific to the interface that the object was using at the time it failed". The "020e" means... well, it means whatever the author of that interface intended it to mean. (All error codes above 0200 are author-defined.)

These are the hardest errors to track down because their meaning is entirely dependent on what the author of the code that failed intended; there is no universal standard. Some subsystem, perhaps developed by a third party, is failing. If you can figure out what subsystem that is, then you can ask the makers of that subsystem what their error number 020e means.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Actually, I am using a listBox to contain the document(TextBlock doesn't allow so many text, it just trimmed them off) Then I just scroll down and down...and the app exit.