# LongListSelector Load items Infinite

Tags: windows-phone-8, longlistselector

For my windows phone 8 app, my data provider provides 10 items per page and i have to show the results in a `LongListSelector`.

> My first challenge is that it provides data in JSON that i parse to array, so i cannot easily add items in my longlistselector.ItemsSource. Well, will do it somehow by observableCollection.
>
> Second challenge is when user scrolls down to 8th or 9th item i have to load page 2 and so on until it returns items less than 10.

I am done with ItemRealized event, it is called for all 10 items at load so if i load page 2 it will load all the pages before screen loading.

I have checked the TwitterSearch example msdn has but unfortunately its api is expired. Any help?

**EDIT**

For my test projects, item template is below.

```
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <ListBoxItem Margin="20">
                        <TextBlock FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Text="{Binding}"      Margin="0,10,0,0"  Foreground="#343330" FontSize="24"/>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
```

and the binding is below.

```
        ObservableCollection<string> data = new ObservableCollection<string>();
.
.
.
        IsLoading = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            data.Add(string.Format("item {0}", (pageNo * 10) + (i + 1)));
        pageNo++;
        IsLoading = false;
```

itemRealized event is given below

```
    private void LongListSelector_ItemRealized(object sender, ItemRealizationEventArgs e)
    {
        //data.ItemCount = data.ItemCount + 1;
        itemCount++;
        if (itemCount < 100
            && reloadOnItem.Contains(itemCount))
        {
            loadData();
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1. You need to deserialize JSON to object. Use Json.Net.
2. Use ObservableCollection and set ItemTemplate in order to have virtualization.
3. Use ItemRealized and check if the id is 9, 19, etc. to load new items

Comment: In fact as i mentioned, i have implemented the itemrealized but it gets fired for all 10 items as soon i assign the collection to itemssource. any solution on this

Comment: i put a test on it, initially it loads 2 pages and loads 10+10 items. Can i decrease its minimum items from 20 to somewhere 10?

Comment: Do you have ItemTemplate defined? What are you using as an ItemsSource?

Comment: @ToniPetrina in fact it loads 3 pages (30 items) per trip, can i decrease it to 10?

Comment: There is nothing to decrease here actually, your code doesn't check if the loading is still in progress. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381752/continuous-pagination-with-longlistselector